# Use this php code wih WHERE

Tags: php, sql

Can I use this php code wih WHERE? `SELECT SUM(buzz) as buzz FROM $table`
 I want to calculate sumation of some spesific rows.

Comment: surely you can use where clouse in sql  query  in php   let me know about your  code more  like  select SUM(buzz) as buzz FROM $table
WHERE someComlumn IN (your name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want specifically in PHP then this might help you

```
SELECT SUM(buzz) as buzz FROM $table WHERE $where
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use PHP code in an SQL where condition. Databases typically don't include a PHP interpreter.

What you can do is use PHP to generate the where clause that you need.